# Horizontal accordion with Expand/Collapse all or any option

Tags: jquery, horizontal-accordion

I am looking for a Horizontal accordion with option for user to 
expand/collapse all panels or any of the panels.

Right now i came across lots of horizontal accordion plugin like http://nicolahibbert.com/demo/liteAccordion/

All these allows option to open one at a time.

Please give me a hand on this.

thanks,
Cbalan

Comment: How would it work? Would each panel change in width depending on how many were open? Or would the page just scroll horizontally?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/bKZ4t/2/ might help,

Comment: @ChristianVarga : The page would scroll horizontally.

Comment: @Tats_innit : No, in the example you have provided. Only one panel can be open at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try setting collapsible to true and active to none:

```
$("#accordion").accordion({ header: "h3", collapsible : true, active : 'none' });
```